# JavaScript Rock Paper Scissors game

Tags: javascript, while-loop, token

For a task to do with some uni work, I have to make a Rock, Paper, Scissors game using JavaScript. We have to do it variable based and it has to use a while loop.

The game needs to end when either the computer or the user has won three games. Upon running I find an error on line 48 and don't know how to fix it, nor am I sure on how to properly implement the loop. Help would be appreciated.

```js
var cpuWins = 0;
var userWins = 0;
var totalWins=0;

while(totalWins!=5){

    var userChoice = parseInt(prompt("Enter 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, 3 for Scissors"));
    var cpuNumber = Math.random();
    
    if (cpuNumber <= (1/3)){
       cpuChoice = "Rock";
    }
    else if (cpuNumber  <=(2/3)){
       cpuChoice = "Paper";
    }
    else{
       cpuChoice= "Scissors";
    }




    if (userChoice===1){
        if (cpuChoice==="Scissors"){
            userWins++;
        }
        else if(cpuChoice==="Paper"){
            cpuWins++;
        }
        else{
            alert("It was a tie");
        }
    }


    if else(userChoice===2){
        if (cpuChoice==="Rock"){
            userWins++;
        }
        else if{
            cpuWins++;
        }
        else{
            alert("It was a tie");
        }
    }

    else{
        if (cpuChoice==="Paper"){
            userWins++;
        }
        else if(cpuChoice==="Rock"){
            cpuWins++;
        }
        else{
            alert("It was a tie");
        }
    }

    totalWins++
}
```

Comment: It's `else if` not `if else`.

Comment: also `else if{ cpuWins++; }` is missing the condition after the `if` and before the `{`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had syntax errors:

```
else if{
```

was not correct, you need to specify a criteria there

```
if else
```

is incorrect, the correct order is

```
else if
```

I have only corrected the syntax errors, the logic should be figured out by you

```
var cpuWins = 0;
var userWins = 0;
var totalWins=0;

while(totalWins!=5){

    var userChoice = parseInt(prompt("Enter 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, 3 for Scissors"));
    var cpuNumber = Math.random();

    if (cpuNumber <= (1/3)){
       cpuChoice = "Rock";
    }
    else if (cpuNumber  <=(2/3)){
       cpuChoice = "Paper";
    }
    else{
       cpuChoice= "Scissors";
    }




    if (userChoice===1){
        if (cpuChoice==="Scissors"){
            userWins++;
        }
        else if(cpuChoice==="Paper"){
            cpuWins++;
        }
        else{
            alert("It was a tie");
        }
    }


    else if(userChoice===2){
        if (cpuChoice==="Rock"){
            userWins++;
        }
        else if (cpuChoice ==="Scrissors"){
            cpuWins++;
        }
        else{
            alert("It was a tie");
        }
    }

    else{
        if (cpuChoice==="Paper"){
            userWins++;
        }
        else if(cpuChoice==="Rock"){
            cpuWins++;
        }
        else{
            alert("It was a tie");
        }
    }

    totalWins++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned there was just a few small syntax errors with your else if statements. See the snippet below:

```js
var cpuWins = 0;
var userWins = 0;
var totalWins=0;

while(totalWins!=5){

    var userChoice = parseInt(prompt("Enter 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, 3 for Scissors"));
    var cpuNumber = Math.random();
    
    if (cpuNumber <= (1/3)){
       cpuChoice = "Rock";
    }
    else if (cpuNumber  <=(2/3)){
       cpuChoice = "Paper";
    }
    else{
       cpuChoice= "Scissors";
    }




    if (userChoice===1){
        if (cpuChoice==="Scissors"){
            userWins++;
        }
        else if(cpuChoice==="Paper"){
            cpuWins++;
        }
        else{
            alert("It was a tie");
        }
    }


    else if (userChoice===2){
        if (cpuChoice==="Rock"){
            userWins++;
        }
        else if(cpuChoice==="Scissors"){
            cpuWins++;
        }
        else{
            alert("It was a tie");
        }
    }

    else {
        if (cpuChoice==="Paper"){
            userWins++;
        }
        else if (cpuChoice==="Rock"){
            cpuWins++;
        }
        else{
            alert("It was a tie");
        }
    }

    totalWins++
}
```